# input type="text" в IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, вёрстка, css

В верстке поле поиска такого вида
[image]

html-код

```
<div id="search">
                <p>Поиск</p>
                    <form name="search" method="get" action="">
                        <input type="text" name="" class="searchField" placeholder="Найти нужное..." /> 
                        <input type="submit" value="" class="searchButton" />
                    </form>
            </div>
```

стили

```
#search {
    position: relative;
    width: 178px;
    margin-left: 762px;
    padding: 60px 0 0 12px; 
}

#search p {
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #557782;
    margin: 0;
}

#search form  {
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 142px;
    padding: 0 25px 0 0;

}

#search form input.searchField {
    background: url('../images/search_background.png') no-repeat;
    width: 122px;
    height: 37px;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #8e9ea4;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    outline: none;
}

#search form input.searchButton {
    background: url('../images/search_button.png') top no-repeat;
    width: 25px;
    height: 33px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 140px;
}

#search form input.searchButton:hover {
    background: url('../images/search_button_hover.png') no-repeat;
}

#search form input.searchButton:active {
    background: url('../images/search_button_active.png') no-repeat;
}
```

в браузере ie9 и ie8 когда в поисковое поле вводится длинная строка, она начинает наползать на левую границу текстового поля
[image]
а в ie7 начинает сдвигаться влево само поле
[image]

подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему?

вот код http://jsfiddle.net/eetZz/5/ , но почему-то на jsfiddle не отображается ничего, хотя все картинки залиты.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не присваивайте картинку бэкграундом к полю input. Оберните input в див и диву задайте бэкграунд. А сам input сделайте прозрачным :) без границ, бэкграунда и прочей атрибутики.

Comment: то есть, каждый инпут обернуть в див? или только текстовый? как тут лучше сделать?

Comment: input.searchField вот этот инпут (текстовый в вашем случае :) ). Со вторым инпутом все ок, там просто картинка-кнопка, проблем с ним нет

Comment: большое спасибо, помогло)))